# Cant change the format of a column in excel

Tags: excel

I tried to use the format cells option on the entire column the data in that column doesn't change.

I had a column in excel that has date in `dd:mm:yy hh:mm` . It had spaces so used the `TRIM()` command to remove the extra spaces. I copied the newly created values(which looked like a long set of numbers, eg: `63756.56`) into another column and when I used the format cells options to format the entire column with a desired date format the format doesn't change.

Link to excel file: https://xgj08-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/jaisonrajan_xgj08_onmicrosoft_com/EeScW62uG3BMqZT2LQ_EdTwBMxnXELj3fdOT36p_UZq_KQ?e=FIvLWY

Comment: May be they are text. Use `--` to suppress those texts to date values. Try `=--TRIM(cells)`

Comment: I cannot reach your link.

Comment: If your original cell displayed as date, then the internal value is a number. It cannot has spaces. The error is from TRIM function which require a string and also return a string. Don't use it.

Comment: Hey, I habe updated the link to the excel file. it should open now

Comment: I watched your sheet and the values are numbers which can be copy/paste to another cell. If choose `Paste` it also copy/paste formatting of the cell. Sidenote: On the Chromeopen only with `Enter` i can paste the values